# Is Azure Managed Identity enabled for Windows desktop app?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

I followed the instructions in this tutorial (option #1 auto-configure): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop

The generated WPF desktop app works fine and I am able to get it to authenticate to my Azure AD account.

Does this mean that the desktop app is using Azure Managed Identity?

If not, what else do I have to do to accomplish this?

My ultimate goal is to be able to modify the desktop application and access secrets in Azure Key Vault, without having to hardcode credentials or use environment variables.

Comment: Maybe if the desktop application will run on VM hosted in Azure. Otherwise, if you do not want to hardcode environment variables you can use something like TokenCredential, the idea is that your WPF application will redirect the user interactively to the browser, after entering the credentials the WPF app will receive a token for accessing some Azure service, the same technique is used by Azure CLI on windows

Comment: Check it here [Desktop and mobile app sign-in flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-sign-in-flow#desktop-and-mobile-app-sign-in-flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that the desktop app is using Azure Managed Identity?

No, it does not mean that, the desktop app from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-windows-desktop) just uses an AAD App for you to login, nothing related to the managed identity(MSI).

> If not, what else do I have to do to accomplish this?

If you want to use MSI to access secrets in azure keyvault, you need to run your code in [azure services that supported MSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/services-support-managed-identities) e.g. azure app service, azure VM, etc, MSI is not available anywhere else.

For the code, just use the [Azure Key Vault secret client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets), it uses `DefaultAzureCredential` to auth, it will try several auth ways automatically, one of them is `ManagedIdentityCredential` i.e. MSI.

```
var client = new SecretClient(vaultUri: new Uri(keyVaultUrl), credential: new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

Also you should note, when you use MSI to access azure keyvault secret, it is a non-interactive way and no user will be asked to login(i.e. no user involved), because MSI is essentially a service principal in AAD, when using it to auth, it just makes an API call to the azure instance metadata endpoint to get the token, then use the token to auth.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  You say I need to run my code in Azure services that support managed identity.  **That's the part I don't understand.**  My code runs in the desktop app.  How do I run my desktop app in Azure?  I just don't understand.  I know I am missing a fundamental concept here.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Sabuncu If you are using desktop app, your option is to use azure VM as mentioned in the comment, mount the storage file share both in local machine and VM, then publish your app, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/test-app-azure), in this doc, it uses a VM in a testlab, you could also use a normal [azure vm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-portal), details of mount see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows).

Comment: Joy, thank you.  I think I am beginning to understand now.  My desktop app can access the Key Vault using the client library you referenced, and in that way I will achieve my goal of accessing secrets there.  I think the difficulty I was experiencing in my understanding was that I was thinking my desktop app had to have managed identity enabled.  That is not the case.  My desktop app needs to authenticate to Azure AD, then it simply accesses Key Vault.  I would appreciate it if you would confirm my understanding.  This whole thing is so complicated! :(

Comment: @Sabuncu Yes, you can access the keyvault with  `DefaultAzureCredential` locally, because if you develop your app in VS, it uses the logged-in user account in VS to auth, but if you deploy your app anywhere else, it will try to auth with [others ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet), they all belong to azure ad auth, just different flows. If you want `without having to hardcode credentials or use environment variables`, the MSI way should be more suitable.